# How to get notified when print job is finished, Issue with jpsi.jar file

Tags: android, printing

I was working file transfers from android phone to
printer, using socket connections. That is working fine, but on the
same node, I want that printer should notify back to android phone,
like printing is over or current job is done how? I tried with IPP 
protocol, to use IPP I have used jpsi.jar file, but when I use a file

IPPService
, which is inside this jar, In ADT,wont able to get. How to
solve this problem?

Comment: Which printer are you using ? Tell company name and model.

Comment: As of now I am using hp printers, but I am looking to connect with each and every printer.

Comment: yes I am working on wireless hp printer, and I want for all wireless printer only!!

Comment: Model number of that printer ?

Comment: HP Officejet Pro 251dw Printer
(CV136A)

Comment: Sharp : Any updates??